# Solve an integral equation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integration

Dear Mathematica Users,

I am a physics student (not very skilled with Mathematica) and I have to solve an integral equation. Below is a sketch of my attempt:

```
iterstepGap := (valuesgap = Table[
    {t,
     NIntegrate[
     Exp[2 (tprime - t)] gapStart[tprime]/(3- tprime) EllipticK[Exp[tprime - t]],
       {tprime, -10, t}, MaxRecursion -> 150, WorkingPrecision -> 30] +
      NIntegrate[
        Exp[tprime - t] gapStart[tprime]/(3- tprime) EllipticK[Exp[t - tprime]],
       {tprime, t, 0},  MaxRecursion -> 150, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
     }, {t, -10, 0, 1}];
  approxgap[t_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[valuesgap, t]
)
```

with

```
gapStart[t_] = 0.002 Exp[-t] ((Exp[t] + t)/(t - 1) + 1);
```

The problem is that the function is oscillating very badly. As I said I am very new with  mathematica and I am not quite sure I am doing the right thing... is there perhaps a better method to solve this kind of equation?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You might be better off asking this on the [Mathematica Stack Exchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Moved to Mma.SE: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15897